# вывести значения в одну колонку после GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Tab_1

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3
q               b           51
q               b           52
q               c           75
q               c           77
w               b           51
w               b           53
w               c           21
w               c           23
e               b           115
e               b           85
e               c           21
e               c           23
```

Желаемый результат

```
Column_1    Column_2    Column_3
q               b       51,52
q               c       75,77
w               b       51,53
w               c       21,23
e               b       115,85
e               c       21,23
```

Я написал запрос который групирует строки, по Column_1, Column_2. Но не понимаю как вывести все значения из column_3 в одной строке

```
SELECT Column_1, Column_2, Column_3
FROM `Tab_1`
GROUP BY Column_1, Column_2
```

Comment: см. group_concat() http://old.code.mu/sql/group_concat.html

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере, заранее зная что совпадений всего по два, можно попробовать примерно так:

```
`SELECT a.Column_1, 
       a.Column_2, 
       CONCAT (a.Column_3,',',b.Column_3) as Column_3
FROM   tab_1 a JOIN tab_1 b ON a.Column_1 = b.Column_1
WHERE  a.Column_2 <> b.Column_2
GROUP BY Column_1, Column_2`
```

Если искать оптимальное решение, то вам нужны оконные функции и GROUP_CONCAT.